# How to catch error in JSON response?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, twitter

I'm getting the json data from the twitter using the wordpress function wp_remote_get as below:

```
$response = wp_remote_get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter');
$json = json_decode($response['body']);
```

and it works fine. However, it totally creates the problem on my page if the twitter returns some error. In that case the content on my page does not load after that error part. So how can I catch the error and continue, only if there is no error.

For example if the twitter limit exceeds, it returns following response:

```
{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter","error":"Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour."}
```

From the above responsive, how can i get the error.
I'm trying following, but it does not work (my page does not load at all)

```
if (!isset($json['error']){
    //continue
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to access `$json` as an array, which it is not. It's an object, so use:

```
if (!isset($json->error){
    //continue
}
```

Your page doesn't load because it's causing a fatal error, which in turn produces a 500 internal server error. If you check your error log you'll find:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use json_decode to "transform" your "json string" in an object.

```
$j = json_decode($json);
echo $j->{'error'}
```

Here you will find everything what you need to know about json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: He is already using `json_decode()`, look at the question. Also `$j->{'error'}` is very much undesirable.